# PKCS12 keystore is empty after loading on Android device

Tags: android, kotlin, keystore, android-keystore, pkcs#12

I'm trying to load PKCS12 keystore with a single `SecretKeyEntry` on Android device:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: client_key_11
Creation date: Sep 28, 2023
Entry type: SecretKeyEntry
```

Here is detailed information that I'm able to get using `openssl -info`:

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 100000
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Secret bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: client_key_11
    localKeyID: *local_id*
Bag Type: pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag
```

Finally, here is the code that I use to load keystore:

```
try {
    var keyStorePath = "/path/to/keystore"
    val keyStore = loadKeyStoreFromFile(keystorePath, "password")
    println(keyStore.aliases())
    val retrievedEntry = keyStore.getEntry(
        "client_key_11",
        KeyStore.PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray())
    )
    val entryData = convertEntryToData(retrievedEntry)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    result.error("KEYSTORE_ERROR", e.message, null)
}

private fun loadKeyStoreFromFile(pathToKeyStore: String, keyStorePassword: String): KeyStore {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
        val inputStream = File(pathToKeyStore).inputStream()
        keyStore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
        return keyStore
}
```

However, my keyStore seems to be empty after I load it, even though I can clearly see the original data stored in .p12 file:

```
extra in data 1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.5
I/System.out( 6668): Sequence
I/System.out( 6668):     ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.5)
I/System.out( 6668):     Tagged [0]
I/System.out( 6668):         DER Sequence
I/System.out( 6668):             ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.2)
I/System.out( 6668):             Tagged [0]
I/System.out( 6668):                 DER Octet String[6512]
I/System.out( 6668):     Set
I/System.out( 6668):         Sequence
I/System.out( 6668):             ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.9.20)
I/System.out( 6668):             Set
I/System.out( 6668):                 BMPString(client_key_11)
I/System.out( 6668):         Sequence
I/System.out( 6668):             ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.9.21)
I/System.out( 6668):             Set
I/System.out( 6668):                 DER Octet String[18]
I/System.out( 6668): java.util.Collections$EmptyEnumeration@a1f871a
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I misunderstoodd about the keystore? I have checked the other topics on this type of issue but haven't found any information about it.

I would appreaciate any help or information. Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: PKCS#12 files can be encrypted using different algorithms. The latest version uses AES but in the Java world the PKCS#12 implementation was only able to read the older 3DES version for a long time. Not sure what version of Android supports which algorithms. Therefore my recommendation would be to make sure the .p12 files uses the old 3DES Algo which should be supported by all Android versions.

Comment: @Robert thanks a lot for your answer! I've tried your suggestion and looks like 3DES entries cannot be imported to PKCS12 keystore: I just get "unrecognized algorithm name" for any version of 3DES algo name. There is also a SO question, where OP had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761047/convert-java-jceks-keystore-containing-3des-key-to-pkcs12

Anyways, thanks a lot for your time!